# How to display posts order by thumbnail existence in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, thumbnails

I want to display posts order by thumbnails i.e the post having thumbnails will display first and then display posts without thumbnail.

I found same situation on Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956135/how-can-i-order-by-existence-of-thumbnail-in-wordpress) , But that doesn't work for me. Currently i am using directory+ theme in which i want to implement it.

I tried to make two loops, one loop will display post with thumbnail and second will display posts without thumbnail. But this doesnot work in case of pagination, as the post without thumbnail should on the last page

Here is the code

```
  {var $itemQuery = array(
    'post_type' => 'ait-item',
    'posts_per_page' => $filterCountsSelected,
            //'meta_key'=> '_thumbnail_id',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'ait-items',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $currentCategory->term_id
        )
    ),
    'paged' => $pagination,
)}

 {customQuery as $query, $itemQuery}

 {* Loop for categories with featured Image*}
  {customLoop from $query as $post}
       {if $post->image}

       //Display post with thumbnail

       {/if}  //end of if

  {/customLoop} //end of loop

 {* Loop for categories without featured Image*}

   {customLoop from $query as $post}
     {if !$post->image}

       //Display post without thumbnail

     {/if}   //end of if

  {/customLoop} //end of loop

  {includePart parts/pagination, location => pagination-below, max => $query->max_num_pages} //includes pagination
```

Edited Query 1:

```
{var $itemQuery = array( 
  'post_type' => 'ait-item', 
  'posts_per_page' => $filterCountsSelected, 
  'tax_query' => array(
      array(
         'taxonomy' => 'ait-items', 
         'field' => 'term_id',
         'terms' => $currentCategory->term_id 
      )
   ), 
  'paged' => $pagination, 
 )} 

 {var $itemQuery['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num'} 

 {var $itemQuery['meta_query'] = array(
   array(
     'relation' => 'OR', 
     array( 
        'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
      ),
      array( 
         'key' => '_thumbnail_id', 
         'compare' => '!NOT EXISTS' 
      ),
  )
)}
```

Comment: Before posting here, i tried to make two loops, one loop will display post with thumbnail and second will display posts without thumbnail. But this doesnot work in case of pagination, as the post without thumbnail should on the last page..

Comment: Please provide the code here so that we can able to enhance your code to fix the solution

Comment: Kindly check.. i have edited my question and added code which i tried...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would sort it via foreach assigning number variable if post has thumbnail then used [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

try this,

```
function cmk_load_post_by_custom_order() {
    // Query Argument
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
    );
    //Initization Wordpress Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    $posts = $query->get_posts();  

    $output = array();
    $order = array();

    //Ourput result as Custom Array
    foreach( $posts as $post ) { 
        $has_thumb = has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ? 1 : 0 ; 
        $output[] = array( 
            'title' => $post->post_title,
            'slug' => $post->post_name,
            'thumb' => $has_thumb,//get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID,'full'), 
        );
        $order[] = $has_thumb;
    }
    array_multisort($order, SORT_DESC, $output);
    echo '<pre>',print_r($output,1),'</pre>';
}
add_action('wp_head','cmk_load_post_by_custom_order');
```

**EDIT 1**

My answer above would not work if you are going to use wordpress pagination as pagination relies on query object,

I've done some test and I've come up with the idea of using the `meta_value_num` on `orderby` then set `_thumbnail_id` as meta_key and add relation OR if either `_thumbnail_id` is empty or not, as post without thumbnail will have empty `_thumbnail_id` key.

try this query argument below

```
$args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'posts_per_page' => 99,
        'order' => 'DESC', // Display all post with thumbnail ID first 
        'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num', // order by meta key value
        'meta_query' => array(  //query post based on meta key
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR', // add condition if meta key is exists or not
                array(
                    'key' => '_thumbnail_id', 
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' // include post without _thumbnail_id key
                ),
                array(
                     'key' => '_thumbnail_id', 
                     'compare' => '!NOT EXISTS' // include post with _thumbnail_id key
                )
            )
        )

    );
```

I tested it locally and I got these following result, it query posts with and without thumbnail, I included the thumbnail ID on the result and you can see that the post is ordered base on thumbnail value

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => The Magnificent
            [slug] => the-magnificent
            [thumb] => http://dynamized.dev/dyna/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/happy-hour.png
            [tuhmb_id] => 17
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => The Awesome Company
            [slug] => the-awesome-company
            [thumb] => http://dynamized.dev/dyna/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/comedy.png
            [tuhmb_id] => 16
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Selfieties
            [slug] => selfieties
            [thumb] => http://dynamized.dev/dyna/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/beverage-store.png
            [tuhmb_id] => 13
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => Drunkard
            [slug] => drunkard
            [thumb] => http://dynamized.dev/dyna/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/restaurant31.png
            [tuhmb_id] => 9
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => My First Company
            [slug] => my-first-company
            [thumb] => http://dynamized.dev/dyna/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/party.png
            [tuhmb_id] => 7
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [title] => No Thumb Compnay
            [slug] => no-thumb-compnay
            [thumb] => 
            [tuhmb_id] => 
        )

)
```

**EDIT 2**

You can also try using array value on `orderby` and use `meta_value_num` with fallback to `date` which display all posts with thumbnail id then sorted by date then all posts without thumbnail ID

change the argument parameter to this,

```
    'orderby'   => 'date, meta_value_num', // order by meta key value
```

Comment: but what should i do in case of pagination because those posts who don't have images should be listed on last page of pagination?

Comment: Not work in with pagination for me.. Here is my query..  {var $itemQuery = array(
  'post_type' => 'ait-item',
  'posts_per_page' => $filterCountsSelected,
  'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'ait-items',
    'field' => 'term_id','terms' => $currentCategory->term_id
   )),
 'paged' => $pagination,
 )}     {var $itemQuery['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num'}
                {var $itemQuery['meta_query'] = array(array('relation' => 'OR', array( 'key' => '_thumbnail_id','compare' => 'NOT EXISTS', ), array( 'key' => '_thumbnail_id',  'compare' => '!NOT EXISTS' ),))}

Comment: {var $itemQuery['order'] = 'DESC'}

Comment: can you post your whole query argument on your question to be more clear, seems like you have lots argument in there

Comment: also, what do you mean is not working? the paging? is it  your query that doesn't return anything?

Comment: Paging is Working but posts without thumbnail are not listing on the last page of paging. Also, i have edited my question with new query.. kindly check "Edited Query 1:" above for my new according to your answer. Thanks..

Comment: I need the posts with thumbnail show first and then posts without thumbnail show at the end in paging. Suppose i have 20 post with and without thumbnails and paging is set as 5 posts per page. Out of 20 posts, 10 posts have thumbnails and 10 are without thumbnail. According to posts, paging will list as 4 pages and I want 10 posts which have thumbnail will list between 1 and 2 and the rest 10 without thumbnail will list after them means between 3 and 4. May be now you could understand what i mean.